# Close specific Excel file opened by user from Access-VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I see version of how to do this with

```
Dim ran as Excel.Applcation
```

but the version of Access I am using doesn't have Excel.Application as an option.

I have written the following code that runs, but does not close the file

```
Dim Path1 as String
Dim objXL As Object
Dim xlWB As Object
Path1 = "C:/....."
Set objXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlWB = objXL.Workbooks.Open(Path1)


xlWB.Close False
Set xlWB = Nothing
objXL.Quit
Set objXL = Nothing
```

Comment: Are you trying to close an excel application that has been opened from within Access, or one that has been opened by the user?

Comment: Opened by the user

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code to close all Excel files (already posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45071752/run-a-macro-with-embedded-excel-sheet-in-access/45072192#45072192)):

```vb
Public Sub CloseAllExcel()
    Dim obj As Object
    On Error GoTo ExitSub
    Dim i As Integer
    'There shouldn't be more than 10000 running Excel applications
    'Can use While True too, but small risk of infinite loop
    For i = 0 To 10000
        Set obj = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
        obj.Quit
    Next i
ExitSub:
End Sub
```

But if we're going to close one specific one, we need some Win32 magic that I can't do, but hey, if you can't do something, you can find it on StackOverflow.
Most code by Florent B found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30363748/having-multiple-excel-instances-launched-how-can-i-get-the-application-object-f)

First, declare our Win32 functions

```vb
#If VBA7 Then
  Private Declare PtrSafe Function AccessibleObjectFromWindow Lib "oleacc" ( _
    ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal dwId As Long, riid As Any, ppvObject As Object) As Long

  Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowExA Lib "user32" ( _
    ByVal hwndParent As LongPtr, ByVal hwndChildAfter As LongPtr, _
    ByVal lpszClass As String, ByVal lpszWindow As String) As LongPtr
#Else
  Private Declare Function AccessibleObjectFromWindow Lib "oleacc" ( _
    ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal dwId As Long, riid As Any, ppvObject As Object) As Long

  Private Declare Function FindWindowExA Lib "user32" ( _
    ByVal hwndParent As Long, ByVal hwndChildAfter As Long, _
    ByVal lpszClass As String, ByVal lpszWindow As String) As Long
#End If
```

Then use them to get all running Excel application objects

```vb
Public Function GetExcelInstances() As Collection
  Dim guid&(0 To 3), acc As Object, hwnd, hwnd2, hwnd3
  guid(0) = &H20400
  guid(1) = &H0
  guid(2) = &HC0
  guid(3) = &H46000000

  Set GetExcelInstances = New Collection
  Do
    hwnd = FindWindowExA(0, hwnd, "XLMAIN", vbNullString)
    If hwnd = 0 Then Exit Do
    hwnd2 = FindWindowExA(hwnd, 0, "XLDESK", vbNullString)
    hwnd3 = FindWindowExA(hwnd2, 0, "EXCEL7", vbNullString)
    If AccessibleObjectFromWindow(hwnd3, &HFFFFFFF0, guid(0), acc) = 0 Then
      GetExcelInstances.Add acc.Application
    End If
  Loop
End Function
```

And then use that collection so we can check which one has the workbook open, and close it

```vb
Public Sub closeWorkbook(workbookPath As String)
    Dim excelInstances As Collection
    Set excelInstances = GetExcelInstances
    Dim excelApp As Object
    Dim excelWorkbook As Object
    For Each excelApp In excelInstances
        For Each excelWorkbook In excelApp.Workbooks
            If excelWorkbook.FullName = workbookPath Then
                excelWorkbook.Close False
            End If
        Next excelWorkbook
        If excelApp.Workbooks.Count = 0 Then
            excelApp.Quit
        End If
    Next excelApp
End Sub
```

And then, implement that close function

```vb
Dim Path1 as String
Path1 = "C:/....."
closeWorkbook Path1
```

Comment: What if I only want to close one specific file?

Comment: That is a really complex question, and I doubt it can be done properly. Closing Excel applications you didn't open through Access already isn't easy.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am just going to add a message box telling people to close the file if they have it open at the beginning of the process.

Comment: See the current edit to close one specific workbook (I said it was more complex, didn't I?)